# Android resource compilation failed when opening a new project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this error when opening new project with my android studio

Android resource compilation failed Output: `C:\Projects\Popular2\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token)`.

Command: `C:\Users\Personal.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e2bfab9f446f5b6bef325bd9d21fcd8e\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy -o C:\Projects\Popular2\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug 
C:\Projects\Popular2\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml`

Daemon: `AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows` Daemon #1

I have tried to clean and rebuild the app but didn't help! 
Any help ?

Comment: Can you post the content of C:\Projects\Popular2\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml? There could be an extra space between the opening bracket `<` and the XML node.

Answer (score 1):

You should :
Go to your project location

1. delete the `drawable-v24` folder.
2. delete the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` if exist.
3. rebuild your project.

Comment: Thanks ! you save my day.